# Como puedo abrir mas de 56 mil url en chrome?

Tags: asp.net

tengo un problema tengo un bloc de notas con más de 56 mil url las cuales debo abrirlas y cerrarlas, mi problema es que no puedo cerrar las ventanas emergentes, ya que cuando ocupo el window.close me cierra la ventana principal y el sistema se cae, alguien me podria ayudar porfavor

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace url.Vistas
{
    public partial class Leer : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fichero = "C:/Users/clira/Desktop/Fichero.txt";
            int i = 0;
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader lector = new StreamReader(fichero))
                {
                    while(lector.Peek() > -1)
                    {
                        string linea = lector.ReadLine();
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linea))
                        {
                            string url = linea;
                            string url2 = "http://" + url;
                            lblLeer.Text = url2;
                            string ventana = "<script> window.open('" + lblLeer.Text + "','_blank','width=800,height=500,top=250,left=200,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no') </script>";
                            Response.Write(ventana);
                            
                            Response.Write("<script> window.close(ventana) </script>");

                            i = i + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    txtLineas.Text = i.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el objetivo de eso?

Comment: cada url manda un codigo a los telefonos, y ese proceso debe ser automatico

Comment: Es más eficiente si haces peticiones Http desde el código. No necesitas abrir y cerrar ventanas en el navegador.

Comment: y eso como sería???

Comment: Con qué frecuencia se envían esos códigos?

Comment: una petición POST/GET a cada URL, ¿Has investigado algo más aparte de querer abrir miles de pestañas en el Chrome?

Comment: Explica por favor en la pregunta para que quieres hacer eso, no parece ser muy "legal" enviar códigos de forma masiva a teléfonos móviles.